# Question about geometry in triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is as follows
in the given figure $F$ is the midpoint of $DC$ and $\angle CFE = \angle CEF$ prove that
$$\frac{AB}{BD} = \frac{AE}{FD}$$

The figure is here
[image]
According to me the question seems wrong but i cant find a way to prove it could anyone prove the question or can someone disprove the question using contradiction.

Comment: Hint. CEF is isosceles triangle ( why? ) so your drawing can be corrected. Especially CFE nor CEF should be acute angles

Comment: Apply Menelaus’ theorem to $\triangle ADC$ and obtain $\dfrac{DF}{FC}\times\dfrac{CE}{EA}\times\dfrac{AB}{BD}=1$.  Since $\angle CFE = \angle CEF$, we have, $CE=FC$. When we apply this to the equation we obtained from Menelaus’ theorem, it reduces to $DF\times\dfrac{1}{EA}\times\dfrac{AB}{BD}=1$.

Comment: Why doe "according to you the question seem wrong"? I can tell you your picture is *not* to scale [@AdamWrzesiński's comment]   but in geometry problems pictures are frequently not to scale so as to not prejudice the student with faulty invalid assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This statement is correct.**

Consider the triangles $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle BDF$ (see the figure).
Let $\alpha=\angle CFE=\angle CEF$ and $\beta=\angle ABE$.
By the law of sines we get:
$$
\triangle ABE:\ \frac{AB}{\sin(180^\circ-\alpha)}=\frac{AE}{\sin\beta}
$$
and
$$
 \triangle BDF:\ \frac{BD}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{FD}{\sin\beta}.
$$

Since $\sin(180^\circ-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$, it follows that
$$
\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{AE}{FD}.
$$

[image]

Comment: how $\frac{AB}{sin(160-\alpha)}=\frac{AE}{sin \beta}$, could you explain in details?

Comment: @sirous, I have $180^\circ-\alpha$, but not $160^\circ-\alpha$.
Added details to my answer.

Comment: Sorry about typo. +1

Comment: @sirous, It's okay, it happens.  Thank you.